# java передача информации между Thread

Tags: java, многопоточность, swing

Есть `JTextField`, который хочу заполнить данными извне. Но если сервер не доступен, не хочу, чтоб зависло все приложение. Поэтому попытался заполнять его из другого потока, но явно что-то в этом не разбираюсь. И ничего не работает) Подскажите, куда глядеть. сейчас реализовано так:

```
final JTextField weightB = new JTextField();
getBruttoFBd(barcode, weightB);
weightB.setBounds(weightF.getX() + weightF.getWidth() + 10, weightF.getY(), 50, 20);
weightB.setEditable(false);
```

Сам метод для другого потока:

```java
public void getBruttoFBd(final String barcode, final JTextField weightB) {
    Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String t = "0";
            t = SkSocket.patterString("getweight:"+barcode);
            if(t.equals("0")) {
                weightB.setText("База недоступна");
            } else {
                weightB.setText(t);
            }
        }
    });
    t.interrupt(); // В моем понимании должно уничтожить поток, если все ок) но это не точно
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом коде две проблемы.

1. Неправильное использование `Thread.interrupt()`
2. Вызов GUI кода из не-GUI потока.

### Thread.interrupt()

`Thread.interrupt()` нужен, чтоб послать потоку прерывание, которое обычно используется, чтоб попросить поток завершить работу. В вашем случае, это не нужно, так какой вызов, скорее всего (это зависит от устройства метода `patterString`) попросту прервет вызов и поток завершит работу не получив никакого значения и не обновив поле `weightB`.

Поток завершится, когда исполнение функции `run` дойдет до конца. Ситуация, когда вам может понадобиться `interrupt()`, это если вызов `patterString` заблокируется надолго. В этом случае поток `t` просто будет заблокирован. На приложение это будет влиять только таким образом, что если вызывать этот код много много раз, то закончится память у приложения.

Поэтому по-хорошему, делают грубо говоря отдельную кнопку, по нажатию на которую потоку `t` посылается `interrupt()`. Но это нужно делать не в `getButtonFBd`, а именно по отдельному событию, например, кнопку которую пользователь может нажать или по таймеру. Опять же, это будет работать, только если `patterString` обрабатывает `interrupt()` правильно (т.е. прерывает свою работу и бросает исключение [InterruptedException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html)).

### Вызовы GUI кода из не-GUI потока

Вторая проблема, это попытка взаимодействовать с GUI компонентами из потока `t`. Это делать нельзя. Изменять компоненты можно только из потока, в котором запущен цикл обработки событий.

Обработчик, скажем, нажатия на кнопку уже запущен в GUI потоке и там можно это делать напрямую - вызывая методы у GUI объектов. В вашем же случае, когда запущен отдельный поток, можно воспользоваться методами из класса [SwingUtilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html):

```
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            String t = "0";
            t = SkSocket.patterString("getweight:"+barcode);
            if(t.equals("0")) {
                t = "База недоступна";            
            }
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> weightB.setText(t));
        }
   });
```

В `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` передается функция, которая будет вызвана в GUI потоке, как только он освободится, если в данный момент он занят.

Comment: Примерно понял, но вот с обновлением все равно ни чего не выходит. Попробовал сделать как вы написали, ничего не изменилось...

Comment: Каюсь, виноват) все работает, моя невнимательность)